# Nested routes with react router v4 not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have create a route for a page.In side that page I have use 4 component.I have give path to these to these component.In header dropdown I have given links to these components, On first click the path is change. [image]

but in second click the url is change but not redirecting.
[image]

```js
const menu = (
      <Dropmenu>
        <Menu
          key="menu"
          style={{ backgroundColor: '#0f2037', borderRadius: '0' }}
        >
          <Menu.Item key="golive">
            <Link to={'/s/live'} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
              <Icon type="video-camera" />
              &nbsp; Start Live Broadcast
            </Link>
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="mychannel" style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
            <Link to={'/s/profile'} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
              <Icon type="user" />
              &nbsp; Manage Profile
            </Link>
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item key="settings">
            <Link to={'/s/account'} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
              <Icon type="setting" />
              &nbsp; Account
            </Link>
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item
            key="logout"
            onClick={this.logoutCall}
            style={{ color: '#fff' }}
          >
            <Icon type="logout" />
            &nbsp; Logout
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </Dropmenu>
    );
   
  <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
        <Route path="/s" component={GoLive} />
        <Route
          path="/s/profile"
          render={() => (
            <div>
              <ManageProfile descri={teprop} />
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `exact` to Routes will solve the problem:

```
    <Route path="/s" exact={true} component={GoLive} />
    <Route
      exact={true}
      path="/s/profile"
      render={() => (
         <div>
            <ManageProfile descri={teprop} />
         </div>
       )}
     />
```

The `Switch` component renders the first matching route and `/s` is matched in `/s/profile/` .

Answer (score 1):

You can use exact in Route:

```
<Route exact path="/one" component={About}/>
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool